errors importing downdraft cape from metpy
I am trying to calculate downdraft CAPE using the Metpy calc function. Although, when I attempt to import this calculation by using:
from metpy.calc import downdraft_cape
But I receiving an import error specifically saying:
cannot import name 'downdraft_cape' from 'metpy.calc'
Any idea what could be going on here? Thanks!

downdraft_cape was added to MetPy in version 1.6.0, so I would first double check what version of MetPy you’re running with:
import metpy
print(metpy.__version__)


Wonderful! I feel ridiculous for not thinking of checking that. Thank you!!!
